# Is there a way to know the length of the cable used between the connected SFPs on a switching/routing device?

Tags: router, juniper, layer1, optics

I have connected two Juniper routers with a QSFP28 optics and I need to find out the length of the optical cable I have used. Is there a command to check that in the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can find out with optical test equipment such as an OTDR, but not with the less-sophisticated telemetry available in a router/switch.

You can know the path loss (limited by the accuracy of the optics' Tx/Rx power meters) but that loss includes things like bends, dirt, connectors, etc. so it's not usable as a good estimate of distance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below command to check the cable details.

`show chassis hardware`.
Sample output. The description has the cable length detail.

[image]

Comment: ... only for DACs. The OP was asking about 'optics'.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into your post using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The poster is asking about optical cables of unknown length, not DACs with their lengths supplied in the part numbers.